# Error "invalid_grant / Invalid JWT Signature." to get the access token using Oauth

Tags: php, google-oauth, access-token, jwt

For a long time I have tried to solve this problem.
I need to generate a token access with a service account to use the Google calendar application.
First I do the JWT with the library firebase / php-jwt based on a pem certificate where it stores the private key provided by the Google service account
After doing a curl in Google to get the aforementioned token, but it throws me the following error "" invalid_grant / Invalid JWT Signature "

```
$time = time();

$key = file_get_contents("./certs/certificado.pem");
$token = array(
    "iss" => "*****@*******.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "aud" => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token",
    "iat" => $time,
    "exp" => $time+60,
    "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"
);

$jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
echo $jwt;
print_r($decoded);

$decoded_array = (array) $decoded;
$grant_type = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer";

JWT::$leeway = 600; 
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
```

Example where I do the curl to Google to get the access token

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"grant_type=".urlencode($grant_type)."&assertion=".urlencode($jwt));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo($result);
```

Google gives the following error

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature."
}
```

Comment: Hi! Google has a nice example of how to do this with the apiclient library: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong signing algorithm for Google OAuth. Use RS256.

Next, once you have a Signed JWT, you exchange it for an Access Token.

This article shows you the details using Python: [link](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/)

This article shows you the details using CURL: [link](https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-version-2/)

Comment: Look, I've tried the solution you offered me but now it's giving another error. I leave it to you next.
`{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}`

I'm starting to think it's a problem in the library that I'm using

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used wrong `service account ID`.

You are able to find correct on under:
Google console -> Service Account -> Detail -> Unique ID

I must be a long number like: 223334445551115551234